# Search speed for Key/Value pair in Apache lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm new to Apache Lucene. What is the best way to store Key/Value pairs so you can have a better search speed?

I have 2 options:

```
doc.add(new Field("name", "Cake", TextField.TYPE_STORED));
doc.add(new Field("value", "Praline Cheesecake", TextField.TYPE_STORED));
```

then perform a search like this

```
name:"Cake" AND value:"Praline Cheesecake"
```

or

```
doc.add(new Field("Cake", "Praline Cheesecake", TextField.TYPE_STORED));
```

and perform a search like this

```
Cake:"Praline Cheesecake"
```

I think search in second option is faster. Am I right? Do you have other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors) is a good page listing Solr Performance factors.

I'd like to suggest the following:

1. If you can avoid storing the fields in the index, it would increase the performance greatly.
2. You don't have to say "type:cake" and then say "name:cake_name". You can just search by "cake: cake_name". If a specific document doesn't have "cake" field, it won't show up in the result.
3. Set omitNorms=true in your SchemaDefinition for the TextField.

So in conclusion, I would go with:

```
doc.add(new Field("Cake", "Praline Cheesecake", TextField.INDEXED));
```

Since you are beginning with Solr, the [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/resources.html#documentation) is a great place to start.

Comment: can you explain how omitNorms=true optimizes search?